# How to check in a single line that none of the pre-processor macros are defined?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

It's easy to check in a single line if at least one macro is defined:

```
#if defined(A) || defined(B) || defined(C)
    // do something
#endif
```

Also checking in a single line if at least one of the macros is not defined:

```
#if !defined(A) || !defined(B) || !defined(C)
    // do something
#endif
```

**Question:**
How to check in a single line that none of the macros are defined?

I can do it with ifndefs in three lines as follows:

```
#ifndef A
#ifndef B
#ifndef C
    // do something
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

But how to join three ifndefs into a single line?

Comment: what about `#if !defined(A) && !defined(B) && !defined(C)` ?

Comment: Your explanatory text is contradicting your example code.  Please re-read what you wrote and clean it up.  It's unclear.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single line? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnZwinck fixed the explanation.

Comment: @Lundin single line wanted in a code review.

Comment: @talamaki: Why not ask your code reviewer how they'd do it then?

Comment: @talamaki Why? What problem does a single line solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nested `#ifndef` can be joined on the same line with just `&&`:

```
#if !defined(A) && !defined(B) && !defined(C)

#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Emulating your nested `#ifndef`'s:

```
#if !defined(A) && !defined(B) && !defined(C)
  // do something
#endif
```

This checks that none are defined. You say you want "at least one isn't defined", but that's covered by your example with `||`s.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: How to check in a single line that none of the macros are defined?

- To check if one macro is defined: `#if defined A`.
- To check if one macro is not defined: `#if !defined A`. "if not defined A".
- To check if several macros are not defined: `#if !defined A && !defined B && !defined C`.
  "if not defined A and not defined B and not defined C"

Common sense usually gets you quite far in boolean algebra. To figure out the boolean equation for more complex cases, define truth tables. Example:

0 = false (not defined)
1 = true (defined)

```
A B C Output
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
```